# Make button visible on new path drawn on Canvas

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I have a canvas which lets user draw and allow them to save and then share. The issue that I came across is once save button is pressed it is replaced by the share button. Now if the user instead of pressing share, draws something new on top of the existing picture how do I check to if there is a new path, so I can remove the share button and show the save button again?

XML:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/viewd"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="3"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bd"
        android:id="@+id/llFreeDraw" >
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

My paint Java class:

```
package com.test.testing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomView extends View {
    Paint paint;
    Path path;
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    private int cWhite = Color.WHITE;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        path= new Path();
        paint.setAlpha(255);
        paint.setColor(cWhite);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 10, paint);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
            path.lineTo(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

My MainActivity class:

```
layout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.viewd);
        //layout.removeAllViews();
        view = new CustomView(FreeDraw.this);
        view.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layout.addView(view);
...
    View.OnClickListener saveHandle = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new SaveImageTask().execute(null, null, null);
        }
    };
    public class SaveImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
         @Override
         protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) { //Running in background
            View content = layout;
            content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            content.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
            Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/PB");
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                folder.mkdir();
            }
            file = new File(folder + "/pb_image_" + Math.random()  + ".png");
            FileOutputStream ostream;
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
                ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
                bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
                ostream.flush();
                ostream.close();
                isSaved = true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                isSaved = false;
            }
            return null;
         }

         @Override
         protected  void onPreExecute() { //Activity is on progress
             //displayToast("Your image is saving...");
             btnSave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             btnShare.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }

         @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(Void v) { //Activity is done...
            if (isSaved == true) {
                 displayToast("Image was saved.");
                 btnSave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 btnShare.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             }
             if (isSaved == false) {
                 displayToast("Unable to save image. Try again later.");
                 btnSave.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                 btnShare.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                 pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             }
         }
    }
```

How do I display the SAVE button if a new path is drawn?

Image to draw out what I am looking to do...
[image]

I tried changing my Paint class to:

```
package com.test.testing;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomView extends View {
    Paint paint;
    Path path;
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    private int cWhite = Color.WHITE;
    private Button btnS, btnSa;

    public CustomView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint = new Paint();
        path= new Path();
        paint.setAlpha(255);
        paint.setColor(cWhite);
        paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(20);

        btnS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        btnSa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawPath(path,paint);
        canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 10, paint);
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            path.moveTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            if (btnS.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && btnS != null) {
                btnS.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnSa.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            else {
                //do nothing...
            }
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            x = event.getX();
            y = event.getY();
            path.lineTo(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            path.lineTo(event.getX(), event.getY());
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Added the following line in my `ACTION_DOWN` event to hide the SHARE button and display the SAVE button:

```
    if (btnS.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE && btnS != null) {
        btnS.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnSa.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else {
        //do nothing...
    }
```

But I get an error, my LogCat:

```
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at com.test.testing.CustomView.onTouchEvent(CustomView.java:47)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7246)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1875)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7426)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5195)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
09-04 21:35:58.752: E/AndroidRuntime(3835):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any suggestion how to fix it or how to complete the step?

Comment: `findViewById` will look for that view in the *current* view and its children so those buttons references will always be null.

Comment: But isn't the Paint class being called within the Activity and I am just referencing it? What do you suggest than? Can I put the onTouchEvent within the activity and then reference the button?

Comment: Did you tested those buttons being valid in the constructor of the custom view?

Comment: I am doing the following in the constructor: `  if (btnS != null || btnSa != null) {
   Toast.makeText(getContext(), "this", 2000).show();
  }` Will post what happens...

Comment: Can I also do: `layout.setOnTouchListener()` inside my activity and do the same?

Comment: @Luksprog You are right, they are NULL... hmmmmmm

Comment: I've told you that, try `btnS = (Button)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.shareButton));`.

Comment: I get `Activity cannot be resolved to a type` error message

Comment: Well, import the `Activity` with like you would do with any other classes.

Comment: Think I got it... I am testing now :)

Comment: @Luksprog It's working :) Thanks!!! Now I came across another issue... which you might be able to help? Please add an answer for this question so you get credit.

Comment: Done. If you have other problems and I can help, sure.

Comment: What I was trying to do is allow user to select different color to draw on the canvas and thats where the issue is. Although the save button reappears but the when saving the new image it keeps the old canvas. Do you want me to post the code?

Comment: Post a new question as we're kind of offtopic to this question's initial problem. In the new question explain this sentence *but the when saving the new image it keeps the old canvas* - better and post the code you use for saving the canvas/image.

Comment: @Luksprog My question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641034/when-saving-the-new-image-it-keeps-the-old-canvas (Please let me know what else you might need to help me solve the issue) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the `NullPointerException` because the button references are `null` in the `onTouchEvent()` method. This is happening because you look for the buttons with `findViewById()` directly which will look for the buttons only in the custom view and its children. So, instead of:

```
btnS = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
btnSa = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
```

look for the button in the `Activity`(the `Context` parameter passed in the constructor) containing the buttons and the custom view:

```
btnS = (Button)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
btnSa = (Button)((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.saveButton);.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641034/when-saving-the-new-image-it-keeps-the-old-canvas (My question)